# Normal Subgroup and gcd

Tags: group-theory

> $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $\gcd(\text{o}(x),|G/H|)=1$, prove that $x$ is in $H$.

I have done this one by Bezoit's Theorem.How about move with a contradiction!

Comment: Why do you want another argument? And why do you expect a contradiction to be a good way to do it?

Comment: Yes I want another way of proving it! I just want to check if it can be done by contradiction!

Comment: But I asked why you want this. I see no good reason why an argument by contradiction would be anything but convoluted.

Comment: Ohh, and I assume by Bezoit's Theorem, you mean Bezout's identity? (Bezout's theorem is often used to refer to the statement about intersections of algebraic curves).

Comment: Yes Bezout's Identity!

Comment: Assume $x \notin H$, then your proof shows that $x \in H$ which is a contradiction. :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Prove $xH$ has order in $G/H$ dividing both ${\rm ord}_G(x)$ and $|G/H|$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $x \notin H$, then $\bar{x}:=xH$ is not the identity element in $G/H$. Its order $o(\bar{x})$ divides $o(x)$ and it divides also $|G/H|$ by Lagrange's theorem. Since $gcd(o(x), |G/H|)=1$, we have $o(\bar{x}) = 1$, that is $\bar{x}=\bar{1}$ and this is equivalent to $xH$ being the identity element, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply Bézout’s Theorem: let $m$ and $n$ be integers such that $mo(x)+n|G/H|=1$. It follows that $x=x^1=x^{mo(x)+n|G/H|}=x^{o(x)m} . x^{n|G/H|}$. Since obviously $x^{o(x)}=1$, we conclude that $x=x^{n|G/H|}$. Since  by Lagrange any element of a finite group  to the power the order of that group equals the identity element, we have  $\bar{x}^{|G/H|} = \bar{1}$, that is $x^{|G/H|} \in H$, and hence $ x=x^{n|G/H|} \in H$.